# WCF TimeoutException using Callback Channels

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm very new to WCF and am trying to get a business requirement up and running at the moment. To give you some background I require a windows service which can talk to other process (inter-process communication) over .NET products. The idea is that only 1 timer can be running at any one time across all of our products and a central broker will tell each program to start / stop it based on which one the user wants to run.

At the moment I just want to get the same client project running twice to start / stop each other's timers before expanding this to hundreds of other projects.

The error I am getting is below which occurs when the second client connects up and calls StartTimer:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: This request operation sent to net.tcp://localhost:9044/TimeRecordingService did not receive a reply within the configured timeout (00:01:00).  The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.  This may be because the service is still processing the operation or because the service was unable to send a reply message.  Please consider increasing the operation timeout (by casting the channel/proxy to IContextChannel and setting the OperationTimeout property) and ensure that the service is able to connect to the client.
```

I initially thought the problem would be related to concurrent connections / maximum allowed connections. However after setting the below in my App.Config I found the problem still occurred.

```
<connectionManagement>
    <add maxconnection="500" address="*"/>
</connectionManagement>
...
<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ThrottlingIssue">
    <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="500" maxConcurrentSessions="500" />
    </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

Hopefully the code below will be of use

I have the following project structure:
Interfaces - Stores interfaces for the WCF Service and Client Callback. (C#)
Service - Implements the WCF Service and also contains code to deploy as a windows service (C#)
Client - Consumes the WCF service and handles the callback to pause it's timer when a new instance is opened (VB.NET)

**Interfaces**
Callback Interface:

```
public interface ITimeRecordingClient
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void ReceiveMessage(string userName, string message);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void StopTimer(string ID);
}
```

Service Interface:

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ITimeRecordingClient))]
public interface ITimeRecordingService
{
[OperationContract]
void Login(string Username, string Password);

[OperationContract]
void Listen();

[OperationContract]
void StopListening();

[OperationContract]
void StartTimer(string ID);

[OperationContract]
void AddTimer(string ID);
}
```

**Service:**

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class TimeRecordingServiceImpl : ITimeRecordingService
{
  private ApplicationUser _user;
  private List<ITimeRecordingClient> _lstCons = new List<ITimeRecordingClient>();
  private Dictionary<string, bool> _tmrs = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
  public TimeRecordingServiceImpl()
  {
     System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 200;
  }
  public void Login(string Username, string Password)
  {
    var user = new ApplicationUser { Username = Username, Password = Password };
    _user = user;

    foreach (ITimeRecordingClient con in _lstCons)
      con.ReceiveMessage(Username, Password);
  }

  public void AddTimer(string ID)
  {
    _tmrs.Add(ID, false);
  }

  public void StartTimer(string ID)
  {
    List<string> lstIDs = new List<string>(); 
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, bool> kvp in _tmrs)
    {
      if (kvp.Key != ID)
      {
        foreach (ITimeRecordingClient con in _lstCons)
        {
          try
          {
            con.StopTimer(kvp.Key);
          }
          catch { }

        }
                lstIDs.Add(kvp.Key);
      }
    }

    _tmrs[ID] = true;
    foreach (string strID in lstIDs)
    _tmrs[strID] = false;
  }

  public void Listen()
  {
    var connection = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ITimeRecordingClient>();
    _lstCons.Add(connection);
  }

  public void StopListening()
  {
    var con = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ITimeRecordingClient>();
    _lstCons.Remove(con);
  }
}
```

**Client**
Main Form:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private _channelFactory As DuplexChannelFactory(Of ITimeRecordingService)
    Private _server As ITimeRecordingService
    Private _strID As String
    Private Sub Form1_Closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
        _server.StopListening()
        _channelFactory.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim contract = ContractDescription.GetContract(GetType(ITimeRecordingService))
        Dim Binding = New NetTcpBinding() With {.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered}
        Dim EndpointAddress = New EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:9044/TimeRecordingService")
        Dim endPoint = New ServiceEndpoint(contract, Binding, EndpointAddress)
        Dim clientImpl As New TimeRecordingClientImpl()
        AddHandler clientImpl.MessageReceived, AddressOf ShowAlert
        AddHandler clientImpl.RequestStopTimer, AddressOf StopTimer

        System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 200
        _channelFactory = New DuplexChannelFactory(Of ITimeRecordingService)(clientImpl, endPoint)
        _server = _channelFactory.CreateChannel()
        _strID = Guid.NewGuid.ToString()

        _server.Listen()
        _server.AddTimer(_strID)
        _server.StartTimer(_strID)
        SlsTimer1.ResetClock()
    End Sub

    Private Sub StopTimer(ByVal ID As String)
        If _strID = ID Then SlsTimer1.StopClock()
    End Sub
    Private Sub ShowAlert(Title As String, Body As String)
        Dim info As New DevExpress.XtraBars.Alerter.AlertInfo(Title, Body)
        AlertControl1.Show(Me, info)
    End Sub

    Private Sub SimpleButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SimpleButton1.Click
        _server.StartTimer(_strID)
        SlsTimer1.StartClock()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Callback Implementation:

```
Public Class TimeRecordingClientImpl
    Implements ITimeRecordingClient

    Public Event MessageReceived(Username As String, Password As String)
    Public Event RequestStopTimer(ID As String)
    Public Sub ReceiveMessage(Username As String, Password As String) Implements ITimeRecordingClient.ReceiveMessage
        RaiseEvent MessageReceived(Username, Password)
    End Sub

    Public Sub StopTimer(ID As String) Implements ITimeRecordingClient.StopTimer
        RaiseEvent RequestStopTimer(ID)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done quite a bit of investigation into my problem and have discovered that it was due to me looping through all open connections to tell them to stop the timer, that *included* the connection that was currently calling my event and therefore trying to access the callback channel caused a block.

**You cannot access a callback channel during the processing of a request**

I implemented the below code change to fix the problem:

Before:

```
try
{
  con.StopTimer(kvp.Key);
}
catch { }
```

After:

```
try
{
  if (OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ITimeRecordingClient>() != con)
  {
    con.StopTimer(kvp.Key);
  }
}
catch { }
```